# Ext JS 3 FitLayout is not extending element to its container

Tags: extjs

I have tried to add panels etc. to TabPanel, but for some reason even I have set added Panels (these elements contains other elements, for example one element contains EditorGridPanel) layout to FitLayout, only visible thing is line at the top of the container, so its not really fitted well and as I would have expected it to be fitted in container.

How can I debug this, because there are no JavaScript errors?

Creation of panel :

```
function getPanel() {

    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout:'fit'
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        title: 'mytitle',
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px',
        store: store,
        cm: cm,
        frame: true,
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        bbar: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function() {
                store.save();
            }
        }]
    });

    panel.add(grid);    
    return panel;
}
```

Creation of TabPanel

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab: 0,
    plain:true,
    autoScroll: true,
    defaults:{autoScroll: true}
});

var panel = getPanel();
tabs.add(panel);

window = new Ext.Window({       
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
    layout: 'vbox',
    modal: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    buttons: [],
    items: [tabs]
});
```

Comment: Provide some code. I expect you have a layout Problem here. And no, you cannot debug this with common tools.

Comment: Now some code added, I had to remove some parts of code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem was with window element, I had to put fit layout to container Window.

```
window = new Ext.Window({       
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    buttons: [],
    items: [tabs]
});
```

Comment: As I told you; a Layout problem ;)